# video.js not playing when adding video element from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code to play video from youtube but for some reason is not working:

```
var content = '{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKRaXPYSzKY" }';
var $el = $('<video id="vid1" src="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="580" height="360"></video>').attr('data-setup', content);
$('#popup-companyPitch').html($el);
```

The same code using php to generate the video element seems working perfectly fine:

```
<video id="vid1" src="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="580" height="360" data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "src": "<?php echo $obj->video_url;?>" }'></video>
```

Anyone knows why the first case is not working using jQuery?

Thnx

Comment: what plugin you use for playing video, if am i right you use this https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/guides/setup.md?

Comment: after adding video if you recall video creation function it will work.

Comment: how do you mean? do u have any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var content = '{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKRaXPYSzKY" }';
var $el = $('<video id="vid1" src="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="580" height="360"></video>').attr('data-setup', content);
$('#popup-companyPitch').html($el);

videojs("vid1", {}, function(){
  // Player (this) is initialized and ready.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.0.0/video.js"></script>

<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.0.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 -->
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.0/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>


<div id='popup-companyPitch'></div>
```

```
var content = '{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKRaXPYSzKY" }';
var $el = $('<video id="vid1" src="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="580" height="360"></video>').attr('data-setup', content);
$('#popup-companyPitch').html($el);

videojs("vid1", {}, function(){
  // Player (this) is initialized and ready.
});
```

Comment: awesome solution :)... u beat me tonight!